# mongoDB how to kill/terminate map_reduce job?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am not sure if this is possible but wanted to know if we have solution for this problem. 
     I have a map_reduce job defined (have taken extra measure to do incremental query so that data set is minimal) if in case it takes long time i want to kill the job either using pymongo API or in mongoDB shell ......and also gracefully delete all the temp tables. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

In terms of killing the operation, what you need there is `currentOp()` to find the op ID and then the `killOp()` command to kill the operation in the shell. See here for details:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Viewing+and+Terminating+Current+Operation#ViewingandTerminatingCurrentOperation-KillinganInProgressOperation

Once the operateion is killed, it is safe to delete the temp collections, it's just a matter of calling `drop()` on the list of colllections.  I could put together some javascript to do it automatically in the shell, but given the potential for error and dropping the wrong collections, that might be a bad idea.